# Accordion body by link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The content bodies of an accordion open by clicking on panels. This is usually what's best. What I am trying to do now is change this behavior so that the content bodies only get revealed by clicking on a link included in one of the panels (or anywhere else, really). Hope that makes sense.

First of all: Is this possible?

This is the code right now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 103%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: -5px;
}

.bg {
 width: 100%;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel {
  padding: 50px 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: groove;
}

.accordion.active+div {
  display: block
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}


    

</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="accordion"><div class="parent">Only the following link should open the content panel: link_1</button>

<div class="panel">
<p>Content 1</p>
</div>





<button class="accordion">Only the following link should open the content panel: link_2</button>


<div class="panel">
<p>Content 2</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Only the following link should open the content panel: link_3</button>

<div class="panel">
  <p>Content 3</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Only the following link should open the content panel: link_4</button>

<div class="panel">
  <p>Content 4</p>
</div>

<script>

function scrollElmVert(el,num) { // to scroll up use a negative number
  var re=/html$/i;
  while(!re.test(el.tagName) && (1 > el.scrollTop)) el=el.parentNode;
  if(0 < el.scrollTop) el.scrollTop += num;
}

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var open = null;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (open == this) {
      open.classList.toggle("active");
      open = null;
    } else {
      if (open != null) {
        open.classList.toggle("active");
      }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      open = this;
      //Scroll to clicked element
      open.scrollIntoView();
      scrollElmVert(open,-68);
    }
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain a little further

Comment: Sure! When you run the snippet here, you can click on any point in a row  and a content body opens, right? The whole row area is basically a link to its content body, it acts as a button. What I am trying to do is overwrite this behavior and only have the content body of a row open by a hyperlink, e.g. just "link_1" in the first row. There shouldn't be anything triggered by any other part other than this hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few changes to the css, but overall its an html issue. You will need to have two different elements or at least different classes to distiguish between the one that opens your accordion and the one that doesn't

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .accordion {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
      margin: -5px;
      display: inline;
    }
    
    .not-accordion {
      color: #444;
      font-size: 15px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .bg {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .active,
    .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .panel {
      padding: 50px 0px;
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: white;
      overflow: hidden;
      border-style: groove;
    }
    
    .accordion.active+div {
      display: block
    }
    
    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 20%;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    /* Clear floats after the columns */
    
    .row:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="parent">

    <p class='not-accordion'>Only the following link should open the content panel:</p> <button class="accordion">link_1</button>

    <div class="panel">
      <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>




    <p class='not-accordion'>Only the following link should open the content panel:</p> <button class="accordion">link_2</button>


    <div class="panel">
      <p>Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <p class='not-accordion'>Only the following link should open the content panel:</p> <button class="accordion">link_3</button>

    <div class="panel">
      <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>

    <p class='not-accordion'>Only the following link should open the content panel:</p> <button class="accordion">link_4</button>
    <div class="panel">
      <p>Content 4</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function scrollElmVert(el, num) { // to scroll up use a negative number
        var re = /html$/i;
        while (!re.test(el.tagName) && (1 > el.scrollTop)) el = el.parentNode;
        if (0 < el.scrollTop) el.scrollTop += num;
      }

      var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
      var i;
      var open = null;

      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          if (open == this) {
            open.classList.toggle("active");
            open = null;
          } else {
            if (open != null) {
              open.classList.toggle("active");
            }
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            open = this;
            //Scroll to clicked element
            open.scrollIntoView();
            scrollElmVert(open, -68);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Awesome! Do you know why these are all aligned in a row rather than separate rows now? E.g. "Only the following link should open the content panel: link_1 Only the following link should open the content panel: link_2" [...] is one row now.

Comment: I'll figure it out! Thanks again :)